# Can't use import in meteor testing

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor

I do not understand this error. Why can't I use `import`?

```
import { chai } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

**package.js**

```
Package.onTest(function(api) {
    api.use('practicalmeteor:mocha');

    api.addFiles('tests/test.js');
});
```

**test.js**

```
import { chai } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';

describe('Array', function() {
    describe('#indexOf()', function () {
        it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function () {
            chai.assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(5));
            chai.assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(0));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The error usually occurs when you use the ES5 compiler instead of ES6 compiler which Meteor uses.

Comment: @AlexCatch How can I change that? I didn't select es5 and I'm using Meteor 1.3

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Which code editor are you using? Do you see in `.meteor/packages` these two added?: `es5-shim` and `ecmascript`

Answer (score 0):

Generally this indicates (as it seems to here) that you didn't include the ecmascript package in your onTest..

```
Package.onTest(function(api) {
    api.use('ecmascript');
    api.use('practicalmeteor:mocha');

    api.addFiles('tests/test.js');
});
```